# how to replace "}" from a String?

Tags: java, string, replace

Well I want to call a

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("}","");
```

but I'm getting error with the } I have tried with:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("\\}\\","");
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("\}\","");
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("//}//","");
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("/}/","");
```

and none of them works. How could I do that?

Thanks

Here's the error:

```
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1:
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030): }
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):  ^
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:1784)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at com.rotaryheart.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4940)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 12:17:44.907: W/System.err(7030):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 12:17:44.915: W/System.err(7030):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-19 12:17:44.915: W/System.err(7030):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
10-19 12:17:44.915: W/System.err(7030):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is the line MainActivity.java 70

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("}","");
```

Well this is my onClick call

```
go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                try {
                  oldString= "} test } for }";

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test for }",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String newString = oldString.replaceAll("}", "");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+newString , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: your first line works like a charm! what's the problem?

Comment: With all the double backslashing it takes for a java regex I'd suggest using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html You can use normal regex syntax, test it, and the tool will show the java regex string.  I will often validate my regex string there before I put it code. Saves me time and confusion.

Comment: Added my error please review it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your first code should work fine. You don't need to escape your `}`.

However, you do need to escape opening braces - `{`, if you are using it.

So the code: -

```
str = str.replaceAll("}", "");
```

works fine. The problem you are getting might be because of something you are hiding from us.

If you have some other regex than the one shown above, then we can't see exactly what the problem is.

Ok, I tried it with your given string: -

```
   String str = "} test } for }";
   str = str.replaceAll("}", "");
   System.out.println(str);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
 test  for
```

As you see I am getting the requried output, but can't understand why this is not working in your code.

But still, you can try using **`replace()`** method, and see if it works: -

```
String newString = oldString.replace("}", "");
```

Comment: Added my onClick, please check it. Thanks

Comment: @RotaryHeary. Try using just `str.replace("}", "");` and see if it works.

Comment: OMG i'm so stupid, I tried like 1 million different things, but I totally forgot about this one... That did the trick :) Thank you so much! You should add it to your answer ;)

Comment: @RotaryHeary. That is good. But still can't understand, why your previous code didn't work.. :( Might be some other reason. But its good that you got it worked..

Comment: @RotaryHeary. Also for your information, `replaceAll()` takes the first argument as `regex`, so you need to escape all special characters. But while using `replace()` you don't need to do that..

Answer (score 12):

`replaceAll` expects a regex and `{` and `}` have a special meaning in regexes. You can use the [`replace` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) instead (which counter-intuitively **does** replace all occurences, but takes the string to replace as an argument):

```
String newString = oldString.replace("}","");
```

Comment: @assylias..  Well, `}` is not needed to be escaped.. `str = str.replaceAll("}", "a");` works fine for me??

Comment: @RohitJain Quickly checking the code, `}` needs no escape if there is no `{` before, but does if there is...

Comment: @RohitJain Yes agreed - his actual code is probably slightly different.

Comment: @assylias. Well just found out that, even if we have `{` before `}` in regex, we don't need to escape `}`.

Comment: @RohitJain The op seems to be on Android - it could be a different implementation in the android JDK vs. the desktop Java JDK.

Comment: @assylias. That might be possible. But I don't think special characters change for Android. This is really strange. But there are many chances that OP is using some other platform.. :-\

Comment: if I change `replaceAll()` with `replace()` it works for `{` and for `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("\\}","");
```

Comment: @TedHopp.. This will not make much of a difference.. Just using it without escaping `}` works fine. Try it out.. However when you use `{` then you need to escape..

Comment: @RohitJain - Yeah, I just discovered that by experimenting. Interesting. I guess it's analogous to how `<` and `>` are treated in HTML--the opening character is always special and the closing character is literal unless there's an unmatched opening character for it to pair with.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
.replaceAll("\\{", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the special character

Try this to escape the brace in the regular expression:

```
\}
```

Which would look like this in Java:

```
String newString = oldString.replace("\\}","");
```

Hint: `replaceAll` is the same as `replace` for most applications

Comment: You also need to escape the `\\` in the source code, and you should either use `replaceAll` with the escape or `replace` _without_ the escape.

Comment: I tried to compile it as it is above, but without the escape, and it read the bracket (I intentionally set it up to where it would cause a "reached end of file while parsing" error, and not escaping the brace avoided the error (reading the brace as code)